# Install windows7 theme ubuntu - fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes

I am trying to install a windows 7 theme on my ubuntu OS.

I follow some steps steps from another site

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50581/is-there-an-ubuntu-theme-available-to-make-it-look-like-windows-7

```
wget http://web.lib.sun.ac.za/ubuntu/files/help/theme/gnome/win7-setup.sh
chmod +x ~/win7-setup.sh
./win7-setup.sh
```

I felt I was almost there but efter entering ./win7-setup I get the following information:

```
 Please use the Gnome classic desktop for the win7 theme installation
```

Ok - so my question why do I get this message? Probably because I dont currently use the "classic desktop" But how then do a classic gnome desktop look like? I made some googling and I think this is the classic desktop (see image).

Would be glad if this could be solved so I can get the win7 theme

cincerely

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That linked question is mostly from 2011 and very often mention that the solutions don't work for Unity, some themes were being "worked on" but either gave up or are taking more than 3 years to complete.

You might be able to install `gnome-shell` and then your method may work, and I'd suggest using a solution for a different Desktop Environment (or at least window manager) like Cinnamon or XFCE (after installing), their linked answers still look good.

Or search the web for a Ubuntu 14.xx (or whatever your version is) Unity theme that looks like Windows

Answer (score 0):

Your are currently running Gnome 3 desktop. What this needs is classic Gnome 2 desktop.

Logout and check the Desktop manager drop-down list. You should have either Gnome 2 or Gnome Classic available. Choose that, login and try again.

Comment: Oopsie! My apology, that is Gnome classing indeed. Sorry, a bit too small picture for my old eyes...

Comment: I just tested this. Downloaded gnome-session-fallback, tested with both Gnome Metacity and Compiz, same failure. I can only deduct that this old stuff is incompatible with new Ubuntu. Note that when you start the installation, you do get a warning it's been tested only on Ubu 10.04 and nothing newer. The best I can offer is http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/make-your-ubuntulinux-mint-look-like.html - at least it's from this year.